# Ncurses prompts look broken in PuTTY from Windows

Tags: command-line, putty

Byobu looks very broken in PuTTY. I've already fixed the key mapping issue, but this issue isn't specified in the man page or even Google:

[image: Broken PuTTY Console]

Notice the misplaced position of the list of windows, the broken selector position, the duplication of the last window, the random a in the top right, and the misplaced apply option. You can't see this, but the last option is not selectable.

Is there some option in PuTTY I need to use in order to see this correctly?

Comment: If someone wants to create the `putty` tag, that would be nice

Comment: I don't have Windows anymore, so I can't test, but I would look into the charset settings of PuTTY.

Comment: Screen is great - you just need to have a decent `.screenrc`

Answer (score 10):

Configure putty to read utf8. 
putty -> config -> window -> translation
 choose utf in "Recieved data in ..."
This is not a byobu issue, it is a putty issue.

See also:

- https://superuser.com/questions/264363/how-can-i-use-utf-8-on-linux-from-windows-7-via-putty
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859565/correct-putty-configuration-for-ubuntu-9-04

Comment: Agreed.  Note that this is specified in the byobu.1 manpage.

Answer (score 8):

Related to Putty, I added this note to the [byobu(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/byobu) manpage a while back:

```
> PuTTY  users have reported that the
> F2, F3, and F4 shortcut keys are not
> working properly.  PuTTY sends the
> same escape sequences as the linux
> console for F1-F4 by default.  You can
> fix this problem in the PuTTY config,
> Terminal -> Keyboard -> Function keys:
> Xterm R6.
```

See:

- http://www.mail-archive.com/screen-users@gnu.org/msg01525.html

Comment: I've already done that to make Byobu at least usable.

Comment: Just to confirm what I said above for anyone else who comes along: I meant that the screenshot above is with putty in Xterm R6 mode. So this isn't a fix for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu uses UTF-8 for its terminal, but byobu appears to use the "ISO-8859-1 (Western European)" charset for it menus. You can set the charset in Window -> Translation.

I've found the following code on the Internet, and I'm still happy with it. `byobu` might have more options, but I like this as well (`~/.screenrc`):

```
startup_message off
hardstatus alwayslastline
hardstatus string '%{= kG}[ %{G}%H %{g}][%= %{=kw}%?%-Lw%?%{r}(%{W}%n*%f%t%?(%u)%?%{r})%{w}%?%+Lw%?%?%= %{g}][%{B}%Y-%m-%d %{W}%c %{g}]%{w} %l'
shelltitle "$ |bash"
termcapinfo xterm ti@:te@
altscreen on
```

Note: for byobu, `shelltitle "$ |bash"` must be removed / commented, otherwise byobu won't work.

Comment: Putty seems to default to `ISO-8859-1:1998 (Latin-1, West Europe)`, so thats not the issue. Switching to UTF-8 made the terminal extremely slow but fixed the menu. What is that code supposed to do though? Didn't change anything in byobu

Comment: By default, screen provides you just a shell with multiple (invisible) tabs. With that code, you can have a fancy shell, with on the bottom a (colored) bar like `[ computername ][  0$ bash  1-$ bash  (2*$bash)  ][2010-12-11 16:24 ] 1.30 1.40 1.43`.

Answer (score 0):

So for byobu to look good in putty you should actually make two changes.

First is change your keyboard to xterm-R6 as already mentioned, but 
second, on your linux machine run the command as your normal user: `byobu-select-backend` and then choose the option `screen` (usually 2).

Should work great now! Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me (fit for Putty - temporary):

> Window -> Translation -> Remote character set: DEC-MCS

For a definitive solution in your application:

1. add in file **.bashrc** (for olny current user) or add in etc/bash.bashrc (for all users)

> NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS=1

2. make sure you have:

   - sudo apt-get -install ncurses
   - sudo apt-get install libncursesw5-dev
3. Add in code:

   `#include <locale.h>
   #include <ncurses.h> //change curses
   -------------------------------------
   //add in main
   setlocale(LC_TYPE, "");`
4. Compile the application with **-lncursesw**, something like this:

   > gcc -o arquivo arquivo.c **-lncursesw**