# Installation of MySQL Server 5.5 freezes on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, server, mysql

I try to install MySql Server 5.5 on a virtual machine running Ubuntu 12.04. After executing

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

I get this screen:
[image: ERROR]

It seems that the installation is frozen.

Any idea what's wrong? How can I leave this screen? My console does not react to any keyboard input.

Comment: Can you add -v so it will look like the following: `sudo apt-get install mysql-server -v` and then edit your answer so we have a verbose output to see what's happening.

Comment: This isn't a mysql issue, this is a display/putty issue.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/63983 is the specific answer you need.